# verilog set bus equal to array of struct bits

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to set a bus equal to a bit of a struct, for an array of structs (s.t. the array size == bus size). My struct looks like

```
typedef struct {
  //other stuff
  logic            valid;
} BFRAME_OUTPUT;
```

And I've declared the array of structs and bus like

```
  BFRAME_OUTPUT             bframe_outs[`BSTACK_SIZE-1:0];
  logic [`BSTACK_SIZE-1:0]  valid;
```

I want to do something like either of these to simply make the valid bus equal to the valid bits for the array of structs.

```
assign valid[`BSTACK_SIZE-1:0] = bframe_outs[`BSTACK_SIZE-1:0].valid;
//
// or
//
for(int i = 0; i < `BSTACK_SIZE; ++i) begin
    assign[i] = bframe_outs[i].valid;
end
```

However I get errors when trying to simulate with vcs:

```
Error-[XMRE] Cross-module reference resolution error
/modules/branch_stack.sv, 87
  Error found while trying to resolve cross-module reference.
  token 'bframe_outs'.  Originating module 'branch_stack'.
  Source info: assign valid[(16 - 1):0] = bframe_outs[(16 - 1):0].valid;
```

Answer (score 2):

More importantly, there is another error which you have not shown:

> Error-[PSNA] Part Select Not Allowed testbench.sv, 14   Part selects
>   are not allowed on arrays of classes.   Source info: assign valid[(5 -
>   1):0] = bframe_outs[(5 - 1):0].valid;   **Convert the part select to**
>   **refer to each element individually**.

As the error points out, you need to convert the assignment to part selection. Here, you can use one of the two ways. Either use `logic` as `reg` and use it in `always` block, or use `logic` as `wire` and do some other stuff.

While using it as `reg`, you need to extract the value in some procedural block. So, just remove the `assign` statement and use `alway_comb`. Since you have used `logic` here, no need to change its datatype.

```
always_comb 
    begin
      for(int i = 0; i < `BSTACK_SIZE; ++i) 
        valid[i] = bframe_outs[i].valid;
    end
```

Alternatively, there is a `generate` block to perform certain things multiple times. Note that by using `generate` block, you are providing continuous assignments and using `logic` as `wire`. Here, you need to provide each `bit` signal to the `wire` individually. Here, use `generate` as follows:

```
  genvar i;
  generate
    for(i = 0; i < `BSTACK_SIZE; ++i) begin
      assign valid[i] = bframe_outs[i].valid;
    end
  endgenerate
```

Refer to [SystemVerilog IEEE 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/get-your-ieee-1800/) section 7.2 for structures and this link for [generate blocks](http://asic-soc.blogspot.in/2012/06/verilog-hdl-generate-blocks.html). I have created a working example at [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/tXi) link.

Comment: BTW, in SystemVerilog `always_comb` is preferred over `always @*` to handle constant propagation logic

Comment: Yes, due to zero time execution guarantee and some other differences, `always_comb` is preferable. Thanks for the pointers @dave_59.